# Can I use await page.click(element) to click on a very specific part of that element using playwright

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, playwright

I use the following line to click on an element using playwright

```
 await page.click(text);
```

The element in question is the word "Test".  When clicked, the caret position appears between the "e" and "s" in test - in other words right in the centre for the element.

How can I get it to click at the start of this element - just before the letter "T"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`page.click` accepts a `position` option that can be used to specify the point to click, relative to the top-left corner of the element. [API docs](https://playwright.dev/#path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=pageclickselector-options).

```js
await page.click(text, {position: {x: 5, y: 5}});
```